# Showing that a group is isomorphic to a subgroup of the direct product of two factor groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm working on the following question:

> If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$, and $H\cap K = \{id\}$, then show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the direct product group $\frac{G}{H} \times \frac{G}{K}$

I'm really not sure how to proceed with this. I'm familiar with the Isomorphism Theorems, and this question comes from the same section of my textbook, so perhaps they're related. However I don't see how to relate this to a direct product group, much less a direct product.

I also know that for two subgroups $H,K$, if elements of $H$ and $K$ commute with each other and $G=HK$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $H \times K$.

I'm just not sure how to put things together here. A hint or two would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sketch: The way that these problems always go is that you need to define a map.  There is a natural map
$$
G\rightarrow(G/H)\times (G/K)
$$
given by the product of the quotient maps.  Now, you only need to show that the map is injective.

So, suppose that $g_1$ and $g_2$ go to the same place under the product of the quotients.  Therefore, $g_1H=g_2H$ and $g_1K=g_2K$ (assuming left cosets).  Now, can you show that $g_1^{-1}g_2\in H\cap K$, so $g_1=g_2$?

Comment: Ok. I defined my map to be $f(g) = (gH,gK)$ since that seemed natural. I was able to show injectivity as you suggested. Finally, I showed that $f$ is a homomorphism by showing that $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ for $x,y$ in $G$. This is enough to show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(G/H) \times (G/K)$, correct? Since I've found an injection that's homomorphic?

Comment: Yes, then take the image of the map.  You can show (or use a theorem to argue) that the image is (1) a subgroup and (2) isomorphic to $G$ (since the map is injective).

Comment: @MichaelBurr we could also prove it in a slightly different (but essentially the same) way, by first noticing that $\{(gH,gK) \mid g \in G \} \cong \{gH \cap gK \mid  g \in G\}=\{\{ g\} \mid g \in G\}$. This then immediately suggests the isomorphism $g \mapsto \{ g\}$ and we are done. Correct?

Comment: @MichaelBurr But we're only required to show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(G/H)\times (G/K)$. Also, there are pairs of cosets with empty intersections (but if they do have an element in common, then that's the only one). The point of my solution is that I couldn't "make sense" of the isomorphism $G \to (G/H) \times (G/K)$, so I tried to visualize it in a different way: the pairs $(gH,gK)$ are unique for each $g$ because the intersection is unique for each $g$, in fact it is $\{ g\}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr can I find an example where the given map is not surjective?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Your question should be asked in a new question, but $H=K=\{id\}$ works.